# Subtract summations with binomials (probability)

Tags: probability, summation, binomial-coefficients

$\sum_{m=0}^{\frac{n}{2}}\binom{n}{2m}(\frac{1}{6})^{2m}(\frac{5}{6})^{n-2m}-\sum_{m=0}^{\frac{n}{2}}\binom{n}{2m+1}(\frac{1}{6})^{2m+1}(\frac{5}{6})^{n-2m-1} = \sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}(-\frac{1}{6})^k(\frac{5}{6})^{n-k}$

Could someone please explain to me how this subtraction works?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 1):

The two series are being interleaved and recast as a single sum.

Notice that in the first sum, $m$ only shows up as the even number $2m$ in the summand.
It hits all the terms of the form
$$\binom nk \left(\frac16\right)^k \left(\frac56\right)^{n-k}$$
with $k$ even, from $0$ to $n$.

In the second sum, $m$ only shows up as the odd number $2m+1$ in the summand.
It hits all terms of the above form with $k$ odd, from $1$ to $n-1$.

The subtraction becomes sign alternation, which we put in the $\left(\frac16\right)^k$ factor since we want it to disappear for $k$ even.